# Is "tickety-boo" connected to "bibbidi-Bobbidi-Boo"?

Tags: etymology, differences

Is there a connection between "tickety-boo" and 
bibbidi-Bobbidi-Boo"?

Comment: If you are the connector,  yes.

Comment: They both end in the same word, "boo".  This is reminiscent of the relationship between words ending in "pity" drawn in the famous Ogden Nash poem: "There goes the wapiti // Hippity-hoppity."

Comment: They're both nonce phrases, made of meaningless but mellifluous parts, ready to play a role in some idiom, in some context.

Comment: All evidence is that the term "Bibbidi-Bobbidi-Boo" did not exist before the song was released in 1949, and the movie *Cinderella* in 1950.  "Tickety-boo" appears to date to the mid 1940s.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is no, the *origins* of 'tickety-boo' (variants include 'tiggerty-boo', 'tiggity-boo' and 'ticketty-boo') and 'bibbidi-bobbidi-boo' are quite separate.

If, of course, you had another sort of connection in mind, phonological, semantic, or psychological for example, then the answer might be yes. An instance of a phonological connection is that both phrases are at least minimally reduplicative. Drawing such phonological, semantic or psychological connections out, however, is not my intent. I'll stick to the origins of the phrases.

First, 'tickety-boo' predates 'bibbidi-bobbidi-boo' by at least a decade. [*OED Online*](http://oed.com/) describes the origins of 'tickety-boo' as "obscure", and speculates that it is "perhaps < Hindi *ṭhīk hai* all right" (where "<" signifies 'from'). The first attestation in the *OED* is dated 1939, and The Word Detective, Evan Morris, concurs that the "phrase seems to have first appeared around 1939". However, in a syndicated column (July 14, 2004; see the online [July 21 issue](http://www.word-detective.com/072104.html)), he goes on to observe that "slang etymologist Eric Partridge asserted that it dates to the early 1920s":

> [image: tickety-boo; origins from Partridge]
>
> From [*A Dictionary of Slang and Unconventional English*](https://books.google.com/books?id=IAjyQdFwh4UC&pg=PA1229&dq=tiggerty&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjJ-bLbk8HQAhVDw2MKHTudCq8Q6AEIQzAH#v=onepage&q=tiggerty&f=false), Eric Partridge, 2006.

The earliest origins I was able to unearth for 'tickety-boo' were the 'tiggerty-boo' variant, first in [*Life* magazine](https://books.google.com/books?id=iEkEAAAAMBAJ&pg=PA21&dq=tiggerty&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjCrI70lcHQAhVDLmMKHfbMB0s4HhDoAQg9MAg#v=onepage&q=tiggerty&f=false) (23 Aug 1940) in a column titled "Arithmetic of War: 18,000 Nazi Planes vs. 5,000 British", next in a column titled "Britain: Thumbs Up Pen Pictures" ([*The Winnipeg Tribune*, 23 Nov 1940](https://www.newspapers.com/image/39354273/?terms=tiggerty)), which contained letters and photos from the front lines. The word 'tickety' itself, however, appeared much earlier in, for example, the phrase 'tickety-toc' (1886 and earlier).

The origins of 'tickety-boo' are certainly not established, but given that there's at least a decade between its appearance and the firmly-dated first appearance of 'bibbidi-bobbidi-boo' (1949), drawing a connection between the two requires that the latter was influenced by the former — and that premise is contradicted by the originator of the latter:

> [image: bibbidi-bobbidi-boo origin; interview with author]
>
> From an interview with Al Hoffman, author of "Bibbidi-Bobbidi-Boo", in ["Broadway"](https://www.newspapers.com/image/21674989/?terms=bibbidi), a column by Mark Barron, *The Times Recorder*, Zanesville, Ohio, 11 Dec 1949.

Therefore, unless the connection was what is called 'unconscious' (that is, obscurely psychological), a connection between the origins of 'tickety-boo' and 'bibbidi-bobbidi-boo' is ruled out by the coiner of the latter phrase.